# How to add command in button control with WPF (Backend)

Tags: wpf, command, controls

How to add command to  button control in WPF with  code in back end?

Comment: could you please be more specific in your question? You want to create a button directly in code or you want to show some command from Viewmodel as button?

Comment: yes I'm creating a button dynamically from code like   var btnCompare = new Button();, but I want to add a command option there.

Comment: This way just set Command Property. You need to instanciate one in backend code, and set this instance value to button Command property through Binding syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example of adding command in code-behind

```
class SomeCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("From command");
    }
}
```

And in your constructor after InitializeComponent();

```
        var btnCompare = new Button();
        btnCompare.Content = "Compare";
        btnCompare.Command = new SomeCommand();

        grid.Children.Add(btnCompare);
```

**UPDATE**

As I understood from your comment, you want to pass a parameter to command, which should change return value of ICommand.CanExecute method based on some condition. It could be achieved by passing a delegate as a parameter and implementing CanExecuteChanged event in your command as a wrapper for CommandManager.RequerySuggested event. Command should fire CanExecuteChanged to notify framework, that return value of CanExecute method is changed.

Typically CommandManager.RequerySuggested fires every time when user interacts with an interface of the application, and for other cases you may call CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() static method.
Below is the code to illustrate the approach.

**XAML**

```
<Grid Name="grid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <CheckBox Content="Bool value is true" Click="checkBoxBool_Click" IsChecked="True"/>
</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
class SomeCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        Func<bool> isTrue = (Func<bool>)parameter;
        return isTrue != null && isTrue();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("From command");
    }
}
```

...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var btnCompare = new Button();
        btnCompare.Content = "Compare";

        btnCompare.CommandParameter = new Func<bool> (() => GetBoolValue());
        btnCompare.Command = new SomeCommand();

        btnCompare.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);

        grid.Children.Add(btnCompare);
    }

    private bool _boolValue = true;
    private bool GetBoolValue()
    {
        return _boolValue;
    }

    private void checkBoxBool_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _boolValue = (e.Source as CheckBox).IsChecked == true;

    }
}
```

Comment: abusing a little bit how can I add a param ? I trying   btnCompare.Command = new ListFolderModel();
            btnCompare.CommandParameter = getBoolValue(); , but I don't know how to catch it for change the value on  CanExecute method

Comment: You may add command parameter as Binding to some other dependency property. Or you can provide your command parameter as Func<bool>, e.g. btnCompare.CommandParameter = () => getBoolValue(); Also CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() method may help. Could you please clarify a bit what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I want to do

Comment: You are welcome! But I'd recommend to stick with classic MVVM approach, with commands, defined in your ViewModel.